# Asp .Net Core policy handler not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Seriously what am i doing wrong here? How is it possible for this to not work if the other policy is the inverse of the other? only 3 letters on the name change and reverse boolean check....

the policy `HasArranqueActivo` is the one working. I used debugger to test and it triggers it.

Here are policies declared

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("HasArranqueActivo", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new HasArranqueActivoRequirement()
    ));

    options.AddPolicy("HasArranqueInactivo", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new HasArranqueInactivoRequirement()
    ));
});
```

As you can see both handlers are basically the same

```
public class HasArranqueActivoHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HasArranqueActivoRequirement>
{
    private readonly NoPaperContext _context;

    public HasArranqueActivoHandler(NoPaperContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasArranqueActivoRequirement requirement)
    {
        // Do something with _context
        // Check if the requirement is fulfilled.
        var registoId = Convert.ToInt32(context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.PrimarySid).Value);
        var registo = _context.Registos.Find(registoId);

        if (registo.IsArranqueActivo)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }            

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class HasArranqueInactivoHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HasArranqueInactivoRequirement>
{
    private readonly NoPaperContext _context;

    public HasArranqueInactivoHandler(NoPaperContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasArranqueInactivoRequirement requirement)
    {
        // Do something with _context
        // Check if the requirement is fulfilled.
        var registoId = Convert.ToInt32(context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.PrimarySid).Value);
        var registo = _context.Registos.Find(registoId);

        if (!registo.IsArranqueActivo)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

On my page i have it wrotten and it does not trigger the policy handler and i keep getting access denied. Why?

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "ProductionAuth", Policy = "HasArranqueInactivo")]
```

**EDIT**

this is the whole startup

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie("ProductionAuth", options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Production/Index");
                options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Production/Logout");
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Production/AccessDenied/");
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            })
        .AddCookie("AdministrationAuth", options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Administration/Index");
            options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Administration/Logout");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Administration/AccessDenied/");
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("HasArranqueActivo", policy =>
                policy.Requirements.Add(new HasArranqueActivoRequirement()
            ));

            options.AddPolicy("HasArranqueInactivo", policy =>
                policy.Requirements.Add(new HasArranqueInactivoRequirement()
            ));
        });




        services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(
            new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/files")));




        services.AddMvc()
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.AllowAreas = true;
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Administration", "/Account");
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Production", "/Account");
            })
            .AddNToastNotifyToastr(new ToastrOptions()
            {
                ProgressBar = true,
                TimeOut = 3000,
                PositionClass = ToastPositions.TopFullWidth,
                PreventDuplicates = true,
                TapToDismiss = true
            })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, HasArranqueActivoHandler>();
        services.AddRouting(options =>
        {
            options.LowercaseUrls = true;
            options.LowercaseQueryStrings = true;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<NoPaperContext>(options =>
        {
            //if(Environment.IsProduction())
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
            {
                sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                    maxRetryCount: 2,
                    maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                    errorNumbersToAdd: null);
            });
            //else if(Environment.IsDevelopment())
            //options.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "AbastecimentoDB");
        });

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddTransient<IComponenteService, ComponenteService>();
        services.AddTransient<IReferenciaService, ReferenciaService>();
        services.AddTransient<IRegistoService, RegistoService>();
        services.AddTransient<IParagemService, ParagemService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseNToastNotify();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `HasArranqueActivoHandler`, you've added a service registration in `ConfigureServices`:

> ```
> services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, HasArranqueActivoHandler>();
> ```

You haven't added a service registration for `HasArranqueInactivoHandler`. Add the following:

```
services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, HasArranqueInactivoHandler>();
```

Implementations of `IAuthorizationHandler` are resolved from the DI container, so this missing registration means the authz system cannot handle the `HasArranqueInactivoRequirement` requirement you've set for the `HasArranqueInactivo` policy.